# Cross compiler not finding SDL package

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

i am cross compiling a small application which uses libsdl (SDL). I can compile using gcc but not able to with cross compiler. the cross compiler i am using is *arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc*. error message come as

*/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL*
although libsdl1.2-dev is installed an i am getting *pkg-config --cflags sdl* output as *-D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL*
and output of *pkg-config --libs sdl* as *-lSDL*. 
Since my native compiler gcc is detecting SDL libs any idea why my cross compiler not able to find the libraries

Comment: Probably because it doesn't find libraries _it can use_. Are you expecting cross-compiled-code to be able to link against a library full of native code? ;)

Comment: my mistake. thank you for pointing it out